# My call for API Post sometimes doesn't seem to work. Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, request

So, for example if I want to get data from the API, I need to run some API called signon to get a unique token and then use the unqiue token for login to get the login session token
so this is more or less the order:

1. do signon (get unique token/authsalt, to be used for login API)
2. do login (get idmitra {used for the next process}, session token)
3. do anything else (for example, get user data etc etc)
4. and so on.

the problem is. the code sometimes works but sometimes doesn't

[image: error]([![https://imgur.com/sg2C1AO]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLiyL.jpg))

for example in this picture, for the first 3 times I run it, it won't get the idmitra from the login process.

I wonder if the problem lies on the server side or it is in the coding in it

here is the coding in the index.js

```
const request = require('request');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const baseUrl = "https://linktoAPIserver";
const username = "theuser", password = "thepassword";

async function syncData() {
    let authSalt = "", token = "";

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // sign on, get auth salt
        request.post(baseUrl + '/api/member/signon',
            { form: { devid: '12345678' } },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    const data = JSON.parse(body);
                    // return authsalt for next process
                    resolve(data.authsalt);
                }
            })
    }).then(salt => {
        const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password + salt).digest('hex');
        // login, get token
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            request.post(baseUrl + '/api/member/login',
                {
                    form: {
                        username: username,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        devid: 12345678,
                        hddinfo: 12345,
                        isbackend: 1
                    }
                },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        const data = JSON.parse(body);
                        resolve({
                            idMitra: data.idmitra,
                            userKey: data.userkey,
                            // get last 8 character of id mitra
                            idMitra8: data.idmitra.slice(-8),
                        });
                    }
                })
        });
    }).then(userData => {
        const trxId = +new Date;
        const signature = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(userData.idMitra8 + trxId + userData.userKey).digest('hex');
        // get laporan transaksi
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            request.post(baseUrl + '/api/member/getlaporan',
                {
                    headers: {
                        sign: signature
                    },
                    form: {
                        idmitra: userData.idMitra,
                        trxid: trxId,
                        // TODO : set startDate and endDate as needed
                        tgl1: '2019-01-01',
                        tgl2: '2020-03-01',
                        produk: null
                    }
                },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        const data = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log(data);
                        resolve({ trxId, signature });
                    }
                })
        });
    }).then(authData => {
        console.log(authData);
    });
}

syncData();
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi, the problem is that sometimes ```data.idmitra``` doesn't have some value, you can check before it use slice if have at least 8 characters or isn't undefined or have some falsy value.

Comment: @OscarVelandia yes that is the problem. I'm wondering what is the cause of it? when I tried to console.log(data.idmitra); it is 'undefined'. even though it should have been getting its value from the API

Comment: First check with console.log the data variable in the function with the error,  if the value isn't the expected, the error is in the data sent from the Client. Another thing you can do is check in the Network tab of the Dev tools.

Comment: The thing i see here is callback hell. I think despite of all this callbacks, both your requests are executing synchronously. And because your second callback depends on data from the first one, the second one is done correctly after the first call fulfills.

Comment: @OscarVelandia sometimes it gets the data correctly. but sometimes it doesn't and idmitra became undefined, that is the reason for the error here. The weird case is, it only happen occasionally. And I just couldn't find the cause.

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk but the problem is. sometimes the data won't be caught correctly. Only sometimes. Kinda random.

Comment: It is because sometimes request is made that fast, that the promise is able to fulfill. But it should be very rare

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk the weird thing is, after I spent more times researching, the problem only occurs on some ISP. For example I am using ISP A, things went smoothly but if I switched to ISP B the same problem occurs. And this is supposed to be ran hourly with a cronjob. I couldn't find the solution to this.